# Calculate monthly value from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file as follows:

```
Date,Data
01-01-01,111
02-02-02,222
03-03-03,333
```

The Date has the following format `YEAR-MONTH-DAY`. I would like to calculate from these dates the monthly average values of the data (there are way more than 3 dates in my file).

For that I wish to use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import dateutil
import datetime
import os,sys,math,time
from os import path

os.chdir("in/base/dir")
data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("data.csv")
data['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Date']).month
mean_data = data.groupby('Month').mean()
with open("data_monthly.csv", "w") as f:
    print(mean_data, file=f)
```

For some reason this gives me the error `KeyError: 'Date'`.
So it seems that the header is not read by `pandas`. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Date` column header is read but put into the index. You got to use:

```
data['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data.reset_index()['Date']).month
```

Another solution is to use `index_col=None` while making the dataframe from csv.

```
data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("data.csv", index_col=None)
```

After which your code would be fine.

The ideal solution would be to use [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)** method. By Default it is comma separated.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
print(pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]))
```

**Output:**

```
0   2001-01-01
1   2002-02-02
2   2003-03-03
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```